# How to do a SQL query without INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a question about some queries I need to do on the Northwind database. I am using SQL Server Management Studio. I've done the work already on all my queries but my professor said he doesn't want us to use the JOIN keyword and I'm having trouble doing it without that. I don't really know how to reword what I've done.

```
SELECT 
    Customers.ContactName, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, 
    SUM(UnitPrice * (1 - Discount) * Quantity) AS TotalCost
FROM 
    (Customers 
INNER JOIN 
    Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID) 
INNER JOIN 
    [Order Details] ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
WHERE 
    ShipCountry = 'Spain'
GROUP BY 
    Customers.ContactName, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate;
```

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: Your current query is fine, and, if I read your question (and the answers below) correctly, your professor is asking you to go back to pre ANSI-92 join syntax, which is bad.  Stick with the query you already have.

Comment: That's what I also see many people say is that what he's asking is bad really. But I have to do it his way for the grade :/

Comment: Then look at the answer by @anonyXmous below.  Again, you should _not_ be using this syntax, but if you have to pass the course, then so be it.

Comment: Perhaps professor meant `OUTER APPLY` for `Order details` summary. Instead of grouping by order header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Customers.ContactName, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate, Sum(UnitPrice*
(1-Discount)*Quantity) AS TotalCost
FROM Customers, Orders , [Order Details]
where Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
and Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
and ShipCountry = 'Spain'
GROUP BY Customers.ContactName, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate;
```

Comment: Oh, okay so I just need to manipulate my where statement and from statement more. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want use Join so you also can use the UNION for joining two tables and their particular fields. you also can see the solution on

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/766095/Join-two-table-without-common-field

Answer (score 0):

You can do join without using `join` keyword by using `where` clause, see the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752673/how-could-i-rewrite-a-query-without-using-joins), and that will fulfil your professor's requirement